# BeanUtils - setProperty on generic array of maps

Tags: java, apache-commons-beanutils

I am trying to use Apache Commons Bean Util on a generic Map like so:

This is the map:

```
public class MyObject {
    public Map<String, ?> attributes = new HashMap<String, Object>();
}
```

Here is a json representation fo what is in the map:

```
"attributes": {
        "attr1": "value1",
        "attr2": "value2",
        "attrN": "valueN",
        "nestedObject" :{
            "nestedAttr" : "value1",

            "nestedAttr2" : "value2"
        },
        "simpleArray":["value1", "value1"]
    }
```

Here is how I am trying to use setProperty to modify one of the values:

```
org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.setProperty(myObject, "attributes.simpleArray[0]", "newValue");
```

Nested properties work fine. However when one of the nested properties is an array I get the following exception:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Indexed or mapped properties are not supported on objects of type Map: simpleArray[0]

This works if I try and set a simple property like:

```
org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.setProperty(myObject, "attributes.attr1", "newValue");
```

But not with an array. What is the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, you can set a new array to the array field but not specific index of the array. Bean utils works on field getter/setters so it can get/set fields of an object but not specific index of array or list or map.